# Como obtener valores de diccionarios anidados y comprobar si un valor corresponde a una clave

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy principiante y me propuse hacer este ejercicio: Cree un programa login que compruebe user y password del diccionario siguiente, solamente con 3 intentos(está en la foto)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Dejando a un lado mi clara inexperiencia, deduje lo que puse en el código, pero no sé cómo validar que el password corresponda a la misma clave que actúa como usser(ni tampoco sé cómo extraer el password de la variable que está en el diccionario anidado)
Si hay alguna forma de hacerlo más eficientemente agradecería la ayuda

Comment: Podrías modificar tu pregunta y añadir el código en vez de una imagen? Así nos resulta mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: Es que solo tengo internet por el móvil(cosas de programadores del 3er mundo) y se me hace súper engorroso escribir código en el. Dificulta mucho la foto?

Answer (score 0):

Los loops `for` tienen una clausula `else` para ejecutar código si no has encontrado lo que quieres mediante un `break` o `return`. Eso es lo que necesitas aprender.

```
for x, y in usuarios.items():
    if user in x and psword in y["password"]:
        break  # Encontrado, rompe el loop
else:
    # Nada ha roto el loop, por tanto la contraseña no se encuentra en ningún usuario
    i += 1
```

Aun así, si te gustaría hacerlo de forma más efectiva (porque un bucle cuando tengas miles o millones de usuarios puede ser bastante problematico) podrías hacer busquedas concretas:

```
if user in usuarios:  # Validamos que el usuario existe como clave en el dict
    if psword in usuarios[user]["password"]:  # comprobamos si la pass coincide
```

Así no tienes que recorrer en bucle los datos.

**Nota:** Como bien indican en los comentarios, es mejor escribir con código que no subir una imagen. Al menos yo, si el código hubiera sido algo más complicado no te habría ni contestado porque tener que re-escribirlo todo da mucha pereza. Intenta solucionarlo de alguna manera para cuando tengas problemas donde necesitemos copiar tu código para realizar pruebas nosotros mismos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue me mucha ayuda. Para la próxima trataré de poner el código. Hasta un nuevo problema :)

Comment: Por cierto, note probando el código que después de loguear correctamente me saltan de nuevo los input, cómo hago para detener el while al poner los datos correctos?

Comment: utiliza un `break` para romper el `while` cuando desees. En tu caso, al encontrar una contraseña válida.